# Spring security - Authentication filters

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I was wondering how can i get spring authentication during SSO.

**A brief on the problem:**

User logins into my app -> Spring custom filter (custom authentication provider for login with SSO) kicks in

> Now that we have an authenticated user (*bob/bob* for example), we're trying to forward the request to a 3rd party application which has its own SSO - problem here is that it has its own in memory authentication (admin/admin for example)

now the 3rd party app prompts for auth (*admin/admin*) and the user bob/bob is now lost. Now when bob tries to log into my app he is not recognized as the session now has admin/admin.

How do i solve this problem, as the session information is being overridden by 3rd party Application ?

SecurityConfig.class

*This would be the security config of ThirdParty App, which gets created when spring context is created*

```
 @Configuration
 @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerBuilder b = new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerBuilder()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").authorities(new String[]{"ROLE_ADMIN"});
        return new CompositeUserDetailsService(Arrays.asList(new UserDetailsManager[]{b.build(), this.technicalUserDetailsService()}));
    }
```

MyCustomConfig.class

*This would be my custom config for security (SSO) also this gets created during spring context.*

```
@configuration
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailService() {
        return new customUserDetailsService(); // Custom SSO
    }
```

SSO is not working, as the fact that my custom config is having different authorities (user/roles) than the third party app.

any help is appreciated...

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more details about the 3rd party application and how you interact with it if you're going to get any meaningful help here.

Comment: ok added some meaning full code snippets -Thanks

Comment: So if I understand correctly the 3rd party application is running in the same Spring context as your app?

Comment: that's correct @Raniz